# mapbox omnivore cannot parse kml string

Tags: laravel-8, mapbox

Currently, i've getting the string data from the maps.kml to display in laravel blade for simple testing. Based on the official documentation, mapbox can parse the kml string to maps. But it wont displayed.

Controller

```php
...
        $excelFile = public_path().'/assets/excel.xlsx';
        $kmlfile = public_path(). '/assets/maps.kml';
        $kmlContent = file_get_contents($kmlfile);
        $kmlLoad = simplexml_load_string($kmlContent);
        $kmlJsonFile = $kmlLoad->Document->Folder->Placemark;
        // $kmlJson = json_decode($kmlLoad);

        $parse = SimpleXLSX::parse($excelFile);
        if ($parse) {
            $petaSheet = $parse->rows(0, 0); //worksheet index, row limit
            foreach($kmlJsonFile as $item)
            {
                foreach($petaSheet as $peta)
                {
                    if($peta[0] == $item->name)
                    {
                        $item->Style->LineStyle->color = $peta[0];
                    }
                }
            }
            // $monitorSheet = $parse->rows(1, 0);

        } else {
            $excelRaw = SimpleXLSX::parseError();
        }
        // $kmlJsonFile = json_encode($kmlJsonFile);
        return view('home', [
            'peta' => $petaSheet,
            'kml' => $kmlContent
        ]);
```

Here the js file inside laravel blade

```js
        var kmlString = "";
        kmlString += `{!! $kml !!}`;
        var runLayer = omnivore.kml.parse(kmlString)
            .on('ready', function() {
                map.fitBounds(runLayer.getBounds());
            })
            .addTo(map);
```

Comment: What are you using to render your map? (leaflet, mapbox.js, or mapboxgl.js?).

Comment: @chriswhong leaflet omnivore, i follow the installation guide from github https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore